# Django: Saving form with User as Foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a problem and I'm looking for the answer like a week ago without finding any.
I want to save a model, using the Django User as a foreign key, I tried creating a new user like this:

```
user=User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
```

And then put the entire user or the user id and does not work, just like this:

```
studio_form.user_id=user
studio_form.user_id=user.id
```

And nothing happens, everything is saved in the database, the user, the group, but not the user as a foreign key, the foreign key user_id is null every single time, help please.

so, this is my code:

**Django Model:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Studios(models.Model):
    user_id=models.ForeignKey(User)
    studio_name=models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

**Django Forms:**

```
from django import forms
from web.models import *

class studioForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Studios
        exclude=('user_id')
        widgets = {
            'password': forms.PasswordInput(),
        }
```

**Django View:**

```
def studio_register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        studio_form=studioForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if studio_form.is_valid():
            studio_form.save(commit=False)
            data=request.POST
            username=data.get("user_name")
            email=data.get("email")
            password=data.get("password")
            user=User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
            group=Group.objects.get(name='studio')
            group.user_set.add(user)
            studio_form.user_id=user.id
            studio_form.save()
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing your data back to the `studio_form` here:

```
def studio_register(request):
    # other view code
    studio_form.user_id=user.id
    studio_form.save()
```

You actually need to pass the data to the `Studios` model in order to save it to the database.  The `Form` is only for cleaning data and temporary holding it until you access the model to save the data to the database.

So if here is you **model**:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Studios(models.Model):
    user_id=models.ForeignKey(User)
    studio_name=models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

You need access it in your **view**:

```
def studio_register(request):
    # other view code
    studio = Studios.objects.create(user_id=user, studio_name=name)
```

That will create a `Studios` object, saving the data to the database.

`user_id` needs to be a `User` object (not the `user.id`) since it is a foreign key to the `User model`. So once you get the user object, then just set the `user_id` in your `Studios` model equal to the `user`.  A better naming convention, however, would be to name the field "user" (in order to avoid confusion):

```
class Studios(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Make sure that you save `studio_name` as well because it is a required field in your `Studios` `model`.

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing it the other way around `user.groups.add(group)` maybe that will work for you?

Comment: that part where i add the user to the group works flawless, but when i add the studio_form.user_id=user.id does nothing, just does not save anything, and the user.id has the id, i print it

Comment: Is `studio_form` of type `Studios`? Also you should be able to just `studio_form.user_id=user`

Comment: No Olly The Ninja, studio_form is an instance of the form studioForm, who is based on the model Studio. And i did studio_form.user_id=user and does not work =(, in the database saves everything excepting the user_id, is null.

Comment: I think this is because only elements that were actually in the studioForm are saved, you may need to override the function that creates the Studios object and save the user there...